# RxJava: Scheduler using more threads than expected

Tags: rx-java

I have following code:

```
ExecutorService poolA = newFixedThreadPool(10, threadFactory("Sched-A-%d"));
Scheduler schedulerA = Schedulers.from(poolA);
ExecutorService poolB = newFixedThreadPool(10, threadFactory("Sched-B-%d"));
Scheduler schedulerB = Schedulers.from(poolB);
ExecutorService poolC = newFixedThreadPool(10, threadFactory("Sched-C-%d"));
Scheduler schedulerC = Schedulers.from(poolC);
private ThreadFactory threadFactory(String pattern) {
    return new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat(pattern).build();
}
@Test
public void testSubscribedOnObservedOn() {
        log("Starting");
        final Observable<String> obs = simple();
        log("Created");
        obs
                .doOnNext(x -> log("Found 1: " + x))
                .observeOn(schedulerB)
                .doOnNext(x -> {Thread.sleep(100);log("Found 2: " + x);})
                .observeOn(schedulerC)
                .doOnNext(x -> log("Found 3: " + x))
                .subscribeOn(schedulerA)
                .subscribe(
                        x -> log("Got 1: " + x),
                        Throwable::printStackTrace,
                        () -> log("Completed")
                );
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log("Exiting");
    }
```

Last 2 operators are to be run on schedulerC. I expect only one thread used for this. But output suggests 2.

```
0   | main  | Starting
72  | main  | Created
135 | Sched-A-0 | Subscribed
136 | Sched-A-0 | Found 1: A
138 | Sched-A-0 | Found 1: B
239 | Sched-B-0 | Found 2: A
239 | Sched-C-0 | Found 3: A
240 | Sched-C-0 | Got 1: A
341 | Sched-B-0 | Found 2: B
341 | Sched-C-1 | Found 3: B
341 | Sched-C-1 | Got 1: B
341 | Sched-C-1 | Completed
3129    | main  | Exiting
```

Sched-C-0, Sched-C-1 are used. Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: Ok, I see that '.doOnNext(x -> {Thread.sleep(100);log("Found 2: " + x);})'..if I remove Thread.sleep, only one thread is used. Seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`, you get a pool of threads that could react to task submissions. It is possible a second thread wakes up faster to service more work before the currently running thread would do it. There is no way to enforce the pool reuses the same thread from its set.

In contrast, RxJava's standard `Scheduler`s use single threaded workers so that the same underlying thread will service the actions in `observeOn`.

When wrapping an arbitrary `Executor`, the best RxJava can do is to ensure tasks submitted to the `Scheduler.Worker` made out of it it don't overlap.